# Representation of the gps point

Tags: c++, point

I have a set of GPS points with following records:

```
point_label    lat       lon      H
FraEur3        N35.3575  E12.4617 207.39
```

I am thinking about suitable data representation for point label.

What is better:

```
class GPSPoint
{
   char * label;
   double lat, lon, h;
};
```

or

```
class GPSPoint
{
   char label[255];
   double lat, lon, h;
};
```

The first option has less memory consumption, but I have to write copy constructor, `operator=` and destructor etc.

The second option is easier to code but has a greater memory consumption.

Which option do you recommend? I do not want use `std::string`...

Comment: The best option is, IMO, `std::string`. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I don't think we can make that decision for you.  You obviously know the pros and cons better then we would.  Which is more important to you memory consumption or how easy it is going to be to code up?

Comment: How many points do you expect to handle this way 5, 50, 5M ?

Comment: The obvious question would be *why* you don't want to use `std::string`. You question is a bit like asking about how to avoid starvation -- but without eating. Yes, IVs can keep somebody alive without eating, but eating is almost always a better choice when possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
class GPSPoint
{
   vector<char> label;
   double lat, lon, h;
}
```

It is not string and dynamically allocable.

Comment: Just to note: vector<char> is very useful, when C functions also used, like Windows API.

Comment: +1 with the last comment added. Unlike `std::string`, `std::vector<char>` is useful if you need a `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `std::string` is *the* solution and I can't imagine why you'd want to avoid it.

To be honest, though, I wouldn't have a label in there at all. Let your point class just contain co-ordinates; you can handle labelling outside of that logic.

Comment: Good point about the separation, though I imagine he'd still come back with the same question about `class POI { <something> label; GPSPoint point; }`

Comment: @dlev: He shouldn't have that. He should have a `std::map<std::string, GPSPoint>`, or something else that integrates into the way he's storing points.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you'll need to allocate memory elsewhere for the string contents. There is absolutely no reason to prefer this to std::string.

You should be able to find documentation on the maximum length of the string to reduce the size of your fixed char array.

I sure hope you have a good reason for dismissing std::string out of hand.